# Not able to export methods using Exporter module in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm trying to export the methods written in my custom module using `Exporter` perl module. Below is my custom module `ops.pm`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter;

package ops;
our @ISA= qw/Exporter/;

our @EXPORT=qw/add/;

our @EXPORT_OK=qw/mutliply/;

sub new
{
        my $class=shift;
        my $self={};
        bless($self,$class);
        return $self;
}


sub add
{
        my $self=shift;
        my $num1=shift;
        my $num2=shift;
        return $num1+$num2;
}

sub mutliply
{
        my $self=shift;
        my $num1=shift;
        my $num2=shift;
        return $num1*$num2;
}

1;
```

Below is the script `ops_export.pl` using  `ops.pm`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use ops;


my $num=add(1,2);
print "$num\n";
```

when i execute the above script i'm getting below error.

```
Undefined subroutine &main::add called at ops_export.pl line 8.
```

I'm not getting why my script is checking in `&main` package even though i have exported  the `add` in `ops.pm` using `@EXPORT`

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: `ops` is a pragma Perl already uses: http://perldoc.perl.org/ops.html Use a different name.

Comment: Also note that all lowercase names are only used for pragmas. Use a camel case name (like `Ops`) for your own modules. And you've mixed up object oriented code and regular functions. Even if the import works, your code is going to fail because you are calling methods like functions. In you call to `add`, the `$self` is missing.

Comment: ***You should have no reason to export methods. They should be called only through an object of that class.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ops` is a pragma [already used by Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/ops.html). From the docs:

> ops - Perl pragma to restrict unsafe operations when compiling

I don't know what that actually means but that's the issue here.

Rename your module to something else, preferably something with uppercase characters as @simbabque suggests in a comment, because lowercase "modules" are somehow reserved for pragmas (think of `warnings` or `strict`).

Also: Calling your `add` function won't work because you mix up OO code and regular functions. Your `add` expects three parameters and you supply only two (`1` and `2`).

When writing OO modules you shouldn't export anything (not even `new`), i.e.:

```
package Oops;
use strict; use warnings;
use OtherModules;
# don't mention 'Export' at all
sub new {
    ...
}
sub add {
    ...
}
1;
```

And then in your scripts:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Oops;
my $calculator = Oops->new();
my $result = $calculator->add(1, 2);
print $result, "\n"; # gives 3
```

Comment: It's also interesting where the custom `ops.pm` file is located. If it's in a directory that is at the front of `@INC` it might work, but could cause all kinds of other trouble.